# PHP root folder

Tags: php, file, root

```
rename('/images/old_name.jpg', '/images/new_name.jpg');
```

This code gives **file not found**.

Script, where files are called is placed inside `/source/` folder.

Files can be opened from `http://site.com/images/old_name.jpg`

**How to get these files from root?**

Comment: [This FAQ question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633753/anybody-knows-a-good-article-on-filesystem-basics) really needs a good answer

Comment: Even when you do it right, the file can take a few minutes to appear on the dest folder if it is a bit large.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[`rename`](http://php.net/rename) is a filesystem function and requires filesystem paths. But it seems that you’re using URI paths.

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to prepend the path to the document root:

```
rename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/old_name.jpg', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/new_name.jpg');
```

Or for more flexibility, use [`dirname`](http://php.net/dirname) on the path to the current file `__FILE__`:

```
rename(dirname(__FILE__).'/images/old_name.jpg', dirname(__FILE__).'/images/new_name.jpg');
```

Or use relative paths. As you’re in the */script* folder, `..` walks one directory level up:

```
rename('../images/old_name.jpg', '../images/new_name.jpg');
```

Comment: instead of rename('../images/old_name.jpg', [...]  I would use rename( dirname(dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_)).'/images/old_name.jpg', [...]  This way it would be relative to the current file (the one with the call to rename) , not the running script, wich can vary if the call to rename is in an included file.

Answer (score 6):

In PHP the root (`/`) is the root of the filesystem not the "webroot". If the php-file is in the `/source/` directory and images are in `/source/images/` then this will work:

```
rename('images/old_name.jpg', 'images/new_name.jpg');
```